# MERN stack , malfunction of my login function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

just found out my login function doesn't work as expected
even I input correct password it still logged me in
but I did put bcrypt.comparepassword
it did match for me

but the error message only showed up in console.log
but didn't stop the login
did I miss something?

below is route

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const foundOne = await User.findOne({ username });
  if (!foundOne) {
    return res.json({ message: "user does not exist" });
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundOne.password);
  if (!isMatch) {
    return res.json({ message: "password incorrect" });
  }

  const JWToken = jwt.sign({ id: foundOne._id }, secret);
  res.json({ JWToken, userID: foundOne._id });
});
```

below is model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    uniqle: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  savedReceipes:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "recipes"}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

below is login page with react

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const [_, setCookies] = useCookies("Jordan_token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/user/login",
        data: { username, password },
        headers: {
          // "Content-Type": "multipart/data-form, charset=UTF-8",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      });
      console.log(result);

      setCookies("Jordan_token", result.data.JWToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem("userID", result.data.userID);
      // window.location.pathname="/"

      alert("Login success, now being redirected to Homg Page");
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.name);
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <form>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div className="formDetail">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="formDetail">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            autoComplete="on"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="buttonDetail">
          <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: You never check if you get an error message or a key. Either check that in the front end or use correct error status on backend to the browser will throw automatically

Comment: oh wait the try catch block in login route? @Konrad

Comment: You never throw any error so there is nothing to catch. Your server always responds with 200 ok

Comment: oh I get it now!!! I will try again 
really appreciate for your help !!!!

Comment: sorry. where should I throw my error 
supposedly in userRoute I guess ?
but how do I throw an error from backend to frontend
@Konrad